Get Ipv6 prefix using ip command in bash script
i have with the command below the ipv6 address on my interface:
> ip -6 a show dev wlan0
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet6 fc00:6666::da3a:ddff:fecf:5023/64 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 86300sec preferred_lft 14300sec
    inet6 fe80::da3a:ddff:fecf:5023/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever 

Inside a shell script i just want to get the global prefix like : fc00:6666::/64

I have only the ip command on my linux system.
I can use "awk", "sed" and "sed" but i'm not familiar with regex.

Many Thanks !

First, fc00:6666::da3a:ddff:fecf:5023/64 is not a global prefix, and it is in a reserved range that should not be used. For ULA you can use the second half of the fc00::/7 range that is fd00::/8, but the next 40 bits of the address must be randomly chosen to give you a /48 prefix from which you can get 65,536 /64 networks.

Hello Ron, it's for internal use with virtual network not connected outside. but thanks

Yes, ULA is for internal use, and you are allowed to use the fd00::/8 range with the restriction that you choose the next 40 bits randomly. It is not like IPv4 Private addressing where everyone uses the same addresses. The "U" in ULA means Unique, and everyone is supposed to get unique addressing so that when companies directly connect or merge there is no conflict. The lower half, fc00::/8 is reserved for a global authority to assign. It is an impovement over IPv4 Priavate addressing.

Also, the question wanted to find the global address, but that is specifically not a gloabal address. ULA lis a local address (what the "L" in ULA means).

I can use "awk", "sed" and "sed why? i'm not familiar with regex The only thing sed understands is regex. Sed works only with regexes. There is almost nothing in sed except regexes. the global prefix like : fc00:6666::/64 What is a "global prefix"? Why is "fc00:6666::da3a" not a prefix"? What about fc00:6666:0000:0000?

@KamilCuk, Global addresses are in the 2000::/3 range. ULA (Unique Local Addressing) is the fc00::/7 range that has some restrictions, and addresses in the range are not globally routable.

$ ip -6 addr show dev wlan0 |
    grep "global dynamic" | awk '/inet6/ {print $2}' | sed 's/::[^/]*/::/'
fc00:6666::/64

Et voilà !

piping grep/sed/awk to grep/sed/awk is an antipattern, see https://porkmail.org/era/unix/award#grep. grep "global dynamic" | awk '/inet6/ {print $2}' | sed 's/::[^/]*/::/' = awk '/global dynamic/ && /inet6/ {$0=$2; sub("::[^/]*","::"); print}'.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Great work also with your command.
thank you Ed !

Using any awk and assuming that ip -6 a show dev wlan0 does produce exactly the output shown in the question:
$ ip -6 a show dev wlan0 |
    awk 'sub("::.*/","::/"){print $2; exit}'
fc00:6666::/64

